# What exactly is the git:// protocol?

Tags: git, ssl, ssh, https

I was checking the ISO OSI chart where you can see the other two protocols git uses:

**https://** (This is HTTP over SSL)

and

**ssh://**

but no mention of **git://**

Here is ISO OSI:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that wikipedia page is not an exhaustive list of layer 7 protocols.

Comment: If you have a better list, please give me the URL ...

Comment: I mean, there are too many layer 7 protocols to maintain an exhaustive list.  IANA does have a port number registry, and there are RFCs from the IETF for many major protocols. The most useful list I could find is https://wiki.wireshark.org/ProtocolReference

Comment: Interestingly that wiki.wireshark.org actually returns "application error Rugged::ConfigError at /ProtocolReference repository path '/var/www/gollum/reporoot/' is not owned by current user"

Answer (score 29):

The **[git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol)**  is a special daemon that comes packaged with Git; it listens on a dedicated port (9418) that provides a service similar to the SSH protocol, but with absolutely no authentication.

It was introduced at the very beginning of Git, in [commit 2386d65 (July 2005, Git 0.99.1)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2386d65822c912f0889ac600b1698b0659190133)

> ### Add first cut at "git protocol" connect logic.

> Useful for pulling stuff off a dedicated server.  Instead of connecting
> with ssh or just starting a local pipeline, we connect over TCP to the
> other side and try to see if there's a git server listening.
>
> Of course, since I haven't written the git server yet, that will never
> happen.  But the server really just needs to listen on a port, and
> execute a "git-upload-pack" when somebody connects.
>
> (It should read one packet-line, which should be of the format
>
> ```
> "git-upload-pack directoryname\n"
> ```
>
> and eventually we might have other commands the server might accept).

The protocol is initially described in the [next commit 9b011b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b011b2fe5379f76c53f20b964d7a3cecb9d8c79)

> There are two Pack push-pull protocols.
>
> - `upload-pack` (S) | fetch/clone-pack (C) protocol:
> - `send-pack` | `receive-pack` protocol

Nowadays, the full characteristic of a git daemon server is described in [**`Documentation/git-daemon.txt`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/git-daemon.txt).

> A really simple TCP Git daemon that normally listens on port "`DEFAULT_GIT_PORT`" aka 9418.
> It waits for a connection asking for a service, and will serve that service if it is enabled.

Note that even though is isn't listed in OSI model, 9418 is still listed from the very beginning as **[IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority)](http://www.iana.org/)**

See [commit ba8a497 (Setp. 2005, Git 0.99.7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba8a4970c790c9a03bb3ed72e24d86bd8aa11a67):

> ### [PATCH] Add note about IANA confirmation

> The git port (9418) is officially listed by IANA now.
> So document it.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), newline characters in the host and path part of `git://` URL are now forbidden.

See [commit 6aed567](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6aed56736b882f94c81293d1646d27d10241349c), [commit a02ea57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a02ea577174ab8ed18f847cf1693f213e0b9c473) (07 Jan 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7b1aaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7b1aaf6d6bb5746a98831854313ca8fccea600d), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git_connect_git()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a02ea577174ab8ed18f847cf1693f213e0b9c473): forbid newlines in host and path
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Harold Kim</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When we connect to a `git://` server, we send an initial request that looks something like:
>
> ```
> 002dgit-upload-pack repo.git\0host=example.com
> ```
>
> If the repo path contains a newline, then it's included literally, and we get:
>
> ```
> 002egit-upload-pack repo
> .git\0host=example.com
> ```
>
> This works fine if you really do have a newline in your repository name; the server side uses the pktline framing to parse the string, not newlines.
>
> However, there are many *other* protocols in the wild that do parse on newlines, such as HTTP.
>
> So a carefully constructed `git://` URL can actually turn into a valid HTTP request.
> For example:
>
> ```
> git://localhost:1234/%0d%0a%0d%0aGET%20/%20HTTP/1.1 %0d%0aHost:localhost%0d%0a%0d%0a
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> 0050git-upload-pack /
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host:localhost
>
> host=localhost:1234
> ```
>
> on the wire.
> Again, this isn't a problem for a real Git server, but it does mean that feeding a malicious URL to Git (e.g., through a submodule) can cause it to make unexpected cross-protocol requests.
>
> Since repository names with newlines are presumably quite rare (and indeed, we already disallow them in git-over-http), let's just disallow them over this protocol.
>
> Hostnames could likewise inject a newline, but this is unlikely a problem in practice; we'd try resolving the hostname with a newline in it, which wouldn't work.
> Still, it doesn't hurt to err on the side of caution there, since we would not expect them to work in the first place.
>
> The ssh and local code paths are unaffected by this patch.
> In both cases we're trying to run upload-pack via a shell, and will quote the newline so that it makes it intact.
> An attacker can point an ssh url at an arbitrary port, of course, but unless there's an actual ssh server there, we'd never get as far as sending our shell command anyway.
> We *could* similarly restrict newlines in those protocols out of caution, but there seems little benefit to doing so.
>
> The new test here is run alongside the [`git-daemon`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a02ea577174ab8ed18f847cf1693f213e0b9c473/Documentation/git-daemon.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon))</sup> tests, which cover the same protocol, but it shouldn't actually contact the daemon at all.
> In theory we could make the test more robust by setting up an actual repository with a newline in it (so that our clone would succeed if our new check didn't kick in).
> But a repo directory with newline in it is likely not portable across all filesystems.
> Likewise, we could check git-daemon's log that it was not contacted at all, but we do not currently record the log (and anyway, it would make the test racy with the daemon's log write).
> We'll just check the client-side stderr to make sure we hit the expected code path.

Comment: I'm just finishing up chapter 3, and putting my notes on google docs if u are interested.

Comment: @cadegalt sure, please leave the url in the comments.

Comment: bit.ly/caa-docs-so - if you have any feedback let me know.  I want to teach this some day.

Answer (score -2):

If i do not understand wrong then you might be asking for GIT Custom protocol URI If yes then GIT URI is `x-github-client://openRepo/<RepoLink>` It opens Repo in GIT Desktop Application.

Hope it will help you or someone.